# QuickBlox - How to get custom query

Tags: quickblox

I have created the custom object class regarding the friend requests and now i want to retrieve the single row value by providing the two fields value e.g selecting the friend request status where userid="xxxxxxx" AND recieverID = "aaaaaaa". In which way should i implement this???

Comment: which platform do you use?

Comment: i am developing the app for android

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
QBRequestGetBuilder requestBuilder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
    requestBuilder.eq("userid", "xxxxxxx");
    requestBuilder.eq("recieverID", "aaaaaaa");

    QBCustomObjects.getObjects(YOUR_CLASS_NAME, requestBuilder, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBCustomObject>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBCustomObject> customObjects, Bundle params) {

            Log.i(TAG, ">>> custom objects: " + customObjects);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> errors) {
            handleErrors(errors);
        }
    });
```